# how to use toString in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

how to use toString() method in arrays bigger than one dimensional for example

```
int[][][] array = new array[x][y][z];
```

print one dimensional

```
Ststem.out.print(array[a][b].toString());
```

print all dimensional

```
System.out.print(array.toString());
```

my console only show :

```
[I@15db9742
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Did you mean Java, which is *a completely separate language*?

Comment: yes in java I don't add java script

Comment: this is java mate no need to tag in javascript

Comment: thanks for your tag edit but can use toString()

Comment: Use Arrays.deepToString(array) fot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multidimentional array so you need to do:

```
Arrays.deepToString(array);
```

or nest for loops and print the element at index **i,j,k**

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like more like Java :).
In any case, I'd create a function that iterates through the different levels and print each element of the array.